# Which part of this circuit plays the role of filtration?

Tags: amplifier, filter

Can anyone say which part of this circuit plays the exact role of filtration and which part plays the role of amplification? How can I find and learn the calculations related to these parts?
It's going to be used for an antenna of a radio telescope. After receiving signals it filters out high frequency ones and amplifies low frequency ones.

[image]

Comment: The entire op amp network does both. Filtering is just attenuation of specific frequencies.

Comment: At least post a circuit that has some popular use. This *looks like* a differentiator and is also badly drawn. Lack of circuit popularity and drawing ineptitude puts me off answering.

Comment: What is the purpose of this circuit?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I edited the text.

Comment: "It's going to be used for an antenna of a radio telescope" - it's taking the signal directly from the antenna? at 11kHz? (that's the center frequency of your bandpass filter). How big is the antenna?

Comment: The problems with your schematic include (1) upside down and sideways GND symbols. They are always draw pointing down to earth. (2) BNC socket shields are normally grounded. You have yours grounded through a capacitor. Explain why you're doing this. (3) It appears you are biassing the inputs to half-supply. R1 should go between R3/R4 junction and pin 2. R2 looks OK. (4) Explain what you intend with TC, C1 and C2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please draw the circuit in the standard form next time!

The opamp is configured as an Integrator in this circuit. The opamp is integrating the input signal rather than amplifying. The bypass capacitors C8,C1,C6 and C7 are filtering unwanted frequencies. TC and C5 are coupling capacitors. They allow only AC signals to pass through and block DC.

Read about: 
1. Operational Amplifier(Opamp) circuits.
2. Bypass capacitors.
3. Coupling capacitors.

Any decent Analog Electronics book should have all these covered.